# Java Executer Service

Tags: java

I have a database result which creating 500 records per one call 
500, then next 500, then next

I need to run a each records which different thread to do the specific task

My examples as follows

```
List<Users> users =  find 500 users
```

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

```
//for each users 
for ( int i =0 ; i<users.size(); i++) {
 Runnable worker = new MyWorker(users.get(i));
 executor.execute(worker);
}

//MyWorker.java

class MyWorker implements Runnable {
User user;

MyWorker(User user)
  this.user = user;
}

@Override
public void run() {
   system.out.println("Start);
    processCommand(this.user);
   system.out.println("End);
}

processCommand(User user){
 //processing
}

}
```

My problem is that before finishing current executer service it getting the next 500 users and trying to start processing ,I need to stop that and until first 500 records processed then start next pool

Comment: you can try using synchronized or lock on list, but if you don't  use them in correct manner causes you application to hung

Comment: Poor title. Please edit to summarize the specifics of your technical issue, to differentiate from all the other Questions among [the 4,953 posts on "Java executor"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+executor).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to have code that at least compiles.  Anyway it sounds like you could use a CountDownLatch to wait for the threads to complete before moving onto the next 500.

```
private void myfunc(List<User> users) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(users.size());
    for ( int i =0 ; i<users.size(); i++) {
        Runnable worker = new MyWorker(users.get(i), countDownLatch);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    countDownLatch.await();

}
class MyWorker implements Runnable {
    User user;
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    MyWorker(User user, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
      this.user = user;
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Start");
        processCommand(this.user);
        countDownLatch.countDown();
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    void processCommand(User user){
        //processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did the same thing but countDownLatch is hanging  after some times :(

Comment: That's probably because your threads never complete.  Instead of printing start and end, dump out a unique ID to correlate the start and end with each other.

Comment: yes you are right tom problen is my exception handling on processCommand method Thanks

Comment: Great! Please mark my response as the correct answer